# What do I need for new home electrical service?

Tags: electrical

I am bring new power into a new building site.  The power company requires that I install a meter pedestal with a disconnect.  I can do this myself or hire an electrician.

Since there is no live power until the meter pedestal is installed and the power company hooks it up, and since there is next to no wiring involved, I think I should be able to do this myself.

Basically it is setting a post, attaching the box, attaching a conduit in which the power company will run the incoming power and driving two ground rods.

The question is, I am supposed to have a disconnect.  Now the meter box has eight slots for breakers and has one 200 amp breaker installed all ready.  It seem to me the 200 amp breaker is the disconnect.  YES?

Comment: I think they want an actual switch, that can be locked off.

Comment: Why don't you ask the power company to clarify?

Comment: The drawing from teh power compnay says disconnect.  It does not say lock-out.  I know in industrial setting they often have locks which can be attached to such devices so people down line can work without the risk of someone turng the power back on, but not in residental settings.  And besides this is an outside meter, 100 feet from teh building, and there is nothing to "work" on between this disconnect and the main house breaker.

Comment: As for asking the power company ... heavy sigh....  The typical answer from power companies and boards like this (present, kind, company, excepted) is if you have to ask hire a professional.  But I suppose I will do that.  I wish I knew of a neighbor with a similar set-up to look at.    The other odd thing is, the box I have purchased has the 200 amp breaker and then a seemingly special slot at the top which teh very brief instructions reference as a disconnect but oddly says it is limited to 50 amps. ???????

Comment: What would such a 50 amp disconnect be wired too?  IF teh 200 amp breaker is still live the the box is live and teh feed out of the box to the house would still be live.  What am I missing here.  Obviously, I have limited knowledge here, but again the main job here is setting the box and ground it.  The power company hooks the power up and then when the house is build a feed is added later (via electrican, likely).  But what is this special slot and would does the power company want?

Comment: How about a call to the local building department?  You should have gotten a permit, and an inspection should be required before power is connected.  The inspector should know what's required in your area, and should be happy to answer any questions you have.

Comment: The short answer is... You'll probably need a separate disconnect, and won't be able to use your load centers main breaker as a substitute (this may vary depending on your location). I'll try to write up a proper answer later, when I have time.

Comment: Many power companies won't even come look at it without a signed inspection in place.  From first hand experience I know this is true in Maryland.

Comment: Tester101:  You say separate disconnect.  As I say the service/meter panel is located 100 feet from the house.  It has a 200 amp breaker.  IT seems to me teh 200 amp breaker is a disconnect!  As if you flip it the service panel and the distribution panel in the house would then be dead.  No?  Thanks.

Comment: If anyone is an actual electrician and cares to devote any time to me, the panel I am looking at is a Square D "Homeline" Combination Service Entrance Device, Model Number SC816D200C (Google Home Depot "Electric Meter Socket).  It has a meter socket on one side and breaker slots on the other side, Home Depot sells it for $137.  Not sure the picture will be of much help.  Thanks.

Comment: Personally, I don't like putting breakers in the same box as the main disconnect. If you ever want to change that box, you need the power company to come pull the meter.

Comment: Jay Bazuzi:  Thanks.  You bring up a good point.  I am not sure what I really need in the box.  Again, basically this is a rural install, teh pwr comp puts in the transformer 100+- feet from teh house, the home owner puts in a meter socket within five feet of teh transform with required disconnect.  Beyond this there are no requirements.  I intend to run the 100 ft to teh main panel in teh house.  The only other requirement for me is teh ability to have one outlet at teh meter and maybe a lighting circuit.  What is an adequate meter/service enterance box for this purpose?

Comment: @alltaken The device you mentioned in a comment should work for what you want.  The terminology you used in your question confused me, and I thought you wanted to use the load center as a disconnect.  The bottom line is, you'll need a meter socket, a circuit breaker style disconnect, and a load center (which will be in the house, once it's built). On the temporary pole, you'll need to install the meter socket, and the disconnect.  Once the house is built, the load center will be fed from the disconnect.

Comment: Tester101.  the Square D box I listed has the 200 amp breaker, 8 slots, and feed through lugs which I would intend to use to feed teh distribution panel inside the house.  The weird thing about this box (SC816D200C) is that it has a separate slot which can take up to a 50 amp breaker, it has reference to it being a disconect, and the slot differs from the 8 other slots which are intended for normal breakers.  What the heck is up with that?  It probably does not matter as the 200 amp breaker is a disconnect and I will use the other slots for outlets, etc.

Answer (score 1):

After reading your comments, it seems you should be alright with what you want to do.

The basic idea is that there has to be a circuit breaker style disconnect outside and away from the house, that can be operated by anybody (non electrician).  If you only have a meter socket a general worker would not have the tools, or knowledge to pull the meter if there was any need (emergency or otherwise) to shut off the power.  You also *may* not be able to use the load center as a disconnect (depending on your location), because at some point the load center will have to be moved into/onto the house. The general setup will look something like this.

[image]

The disconnect will have to be a weather proof, circuit breaker style disconnect.

Comment: @alltaken: I'm confused. Is this for a temporary service until the house is built with a permanent service entrance? This is the usual purpose of post mounted meters. The proper equipment in this case can often be rented. Or is this for the permanent service for the house? In which case this answer shows a proper configuration and I have nothing to add. In other words, will the meter be on the post permanently, or just until the house is ready to have it's permanent meter installed?

Comment: Permanent.  This is a rural install.  The power company desires a meter and disconnect outside and PREFERs not to have it mounted on the house.  I will use the meter/disconnect/loadcenter as a temp service while building.  Later I will have the discconnect on teh post or pedestal and an outlet for outdoor use, I might also run a line for driveway lighting, and or run my well off of it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any specific references but I do know that some municipalities require a service disconnect prior to the load panel. In some instances it must be on the exterior of the building. It could be for emergency personel to kill the power without entering the building or in the event of a fire at the load panel.

Comment: tester101.   It is a bit odd around here.  We don't have a building department, but we do need to get a STATE electrical permit.  There is no state office in town, so you need to get permits via mail or on-line.  There are inspectors SOMEWHERE local (?).  So I suppose I should see if I can figure out where they are and how to contact them.  To be honests, I have heard stories about inspectors not being too happy about non-licensed-homeowners doing work and so I would hope to keep my questions to a minimum.  So try to do my homework upfront.  Thanks

Comment: mikes:  Thanks for your into.  You mention the ability to kill power outside the house.  Not sure if that is why the power company wants a disconnect near teh meter (which by the why is not on teh house but a stand-alone item 100 feet from teh house - this is rural) but the bigger question is, is the 200 amp breaker in the service panel the disconnect asked for or is there ANOTHER item which is the disconnect?

Comment: Could be the 200amp breaker is just that a breaker, not a disconnect.

Comment: Mikes: What is teh difference?  IS and a breaker a discnnect?

Comment: @alltaken It really matters how the law is written as to what can be classified as a disconnect.

Comment: brad: where do you see what teh "law" is?

Comment: Heh, the Law. Doesn't matter. What matters is the power company's interpretation of it. When it comes to this, they are God. If they are not happy, you get no power. That simple. There are numerous disconnecting means, from essentially a double pole knife switch to elaborate microprocessor controlled circuit breakers. Which ones are appropriate is open to interpretation, the power company's interpretation. IF an integrated meter base and load center is acceptable to the power company, the main breaker will serve as the disconnect means. Any other configuration of this device would be very odd.

Comment: Thanks bcworkz.  That is what I thought.  teh 200 amp breaker is a disconnect.  I will confirm this with the power company and or the inspector.